# reading lockout duration policy from AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap

trying to read this from AD, and boy, is the documentation a mess.
Having set it to 15 minutes, I read it in Java using :

```
Attributes attrs = ldapContext.getAttributes("DC=BPLAB01,DC=local"); 
System.out.println("Lockout policy for " + attrs.get("distinguishedName").get());
Long lockoutDuration = Long.parseLong(attrs.get("lockoutDuration").get().toString());
System.out.println("Duration: " + lockoutDuration);
```

Duration: -9000000000

Setting it to 40 minutes yields

Duration: -24000000000

So my simple question is, what is going on here, why this large negative number ?

Comment: FYI, the whole [AD specification is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223122.aspx). I have a local PDF copy in which I do a full text search for an attribute name. But lockoutDuration is not very clear there either. But they do mention that lockoutDuration is *treated as a signed value*. The syntax is [Microsoft Large Integer](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.840.113556.1.4.906.html). HTH and good luck !

Comment: Thanks, I was sort of hoping I would not have to read all of this rather messy doc. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The huge number is a [large integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that represents the negative of the number of **100-nanosecond intervals** from the time the Lockout-Threshold is exceeded, that must elapse before the account is unlocked.

To put it more plainly, what you do is add two 0's to the end of those giant numbers to get the number of nanoseconds:  24000000000 becomes 2400000000000.

We convert that to minutes:
2400000000000 = 40 minutes.

So lets look at your previous value of 9000000000; it becomes 900000000000 once we multiply it by 100 (they're 100 nanosecond intervals afterall!), and now we convert that to minutes (easily done via google) and we can see that your previous value was 0.15 minutes.

The value is most likely stored in a negative form so that it can be used to find the difference from the time the Lockout-Threshold was set.

Comment: Turns out that `lockoutDuration` [**must** be negative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245667.aspx).